# What is the correct way to use a hook while handling an event in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

My goal is to fetch data from an API using a custom hook after changing a Select option.

I have a onChange event on a Select-field that looks like this:

```
<Select options={customers.customers} onChange={updateMarkers} />
```

The function `updateMarkers` that is being called looks like this:

```
  const updateMarkers = (selectedOption) => {
    const warehouses = GQLQuery(`
        {
          warehouses(where: {customer: {id: "${selectedOption.value}"}}) {
            name
            address {
              city
              lat
              lng
              road
              zipcode
              housenumber
              province {
                name
              }
              country {
                name
              }

            }
          }
        }
    `)
    console.log(warehouses)
  }
```

Within this function I call a custom hook (`GQLQuery`) that fetches the data (which works if I am not calling it from an event) that looks like this:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

function GQLQuery(query) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gql`${query}`);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  if (data) return data
}
```

The error I get after selecting an option is:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It is obvious that I am breaking the Rules of Hooks, because I just started using React and I am missing a lot of fundamentals, but I just can't understand what I am doing wrong here. Can someone point me to the documentation that I need to understand or point me towards the solution. Thanks!

Comment: If any extra information is needed, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Using react hooks `useQuery()` inside a function breaks the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

You need to use [query(options): Promise](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.query) method of apollo client to call API manually inside your event handler.

The Apollo client should be connected to React with the `ApolloProvider` component. See [connect-your-client-to-react](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#3-connect-your-client-to-react).

Then, you can use it like `props.client.query({...})` in the event handler of the component.